# Swashbuckle No Operations Defined on PCF. Works local dev

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I have read numerous articles, upgraded, downgraded, even sidegraded and nothing is working to show Swagger definitions on PCF.

What makes it extra tough is that it works locally running VS 2019 IIS Express but when I push to PCF it fails. What I mean by fails is the swagger UI loads but there are no operations defined.

Tech Spec:

- AspNetCoreAll 2.2.0
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 4.0.1
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations 4.0.1
- swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.0
- PCF
- buildpack: dotnet_core_buildpack_2_2_5
- stack: cflinuxfs3

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
            .AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("1.0.0", new Info
                {
                    Version = "1.0.0",
                    Title = "MyAPI",
                    Description = "MyAPI (ASP.NET Core 2.2)",
                    Contact = new Contact()
                    {
                       Name = "Production Support Team",
                       Url = "https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen",
                       Email = "email@domain.com"
                    },
                    TermsOfService = ""
                });
}

public void Configure(...)
{
        .UseSwagger()
        .UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            //string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
            //c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/1.0.0/swagger.json", "ipt-client-mobile-bff");

            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/1.0.0/swagger.json", "MyAPI");

        });
```

[image: Project XML Build]

I also found this: openapi-original.json and that looks a lot like my swagger operations....??

Some things I am unclear on:

I thought the swagger.json was generated on the fly when you hit the /swagger endpoint and the Swagger-UI loads.

However the PCF guy is saying it is generated at build time and the reason it isn't showing on PCF is because my PCF packaging and build process isn't including it.

Whichever it is, I can't find a `swagger.json` on disk, making me suspect it is generated on the fly and in memory.

Also there are no errors thrown in the PCF logs or the F-12 Dev tools.

Comment: Are you including the generated Xml Documentation file with your deployment?

Comment: Perhaps...I thought that was for XML comments...didn't know it had anything to do with the swagger stuff. Will update OP with xml details

Answer (score 0):

Quite interestingly...I removed a 3rd party library because it failed a security scan and then pushed to dev / qa...and my swagger started working again!

I have notified the manufacturer of the third party library of both issues.